# The functor $\textbf{Hom}(-,W):\textbf{Vect}^{op}_k\rightarrow \textbf{Vect}_k$

Tags: category-theory, functors

I've recently started to study category through Leinster's *Basic Category Theory*.

In example 1.2.12 it's said that $\textbf{Hom}(V,W)$ is a vector space.

Then,

> Now fix a vector space $W$. Any linear map f : $V \rightarrow V′$ induces a linear map
> $f^*:\textbf{Hom}(V',W)\rightarrow \textbf{Hom}(V,W)$ such that for $q\in \textbf{Hom}(V',W)$ we have $f^*(q)= q f$

He concludes by saying that

> This defines a functor $\textbf{Hom}(-,W):\textbf{Vect}^{op}_k\rightarrow \textbf{Vect}_k$

My problem is that I don't understand why is the **op** necessary there. Why wouldn't it work without it?

Comment: There also exists a Hom-functor which does not need the "op", namely $\text{Hom}(W,-)$. The point is that if you fix the target (as in example 1.2.12), the natural map switches the direction and therefore ends up needing the "op" on either the source or target category.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **op** is necessary there because one would like to work with covariant functors $F: \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{D}$ between categories which preserve the order of composition: i.e., given a map $f: C_1 \rightarrow C_2$ in $\mathcal{C}$ then we would like $F(f): F(C_1) \rightarrow F(C_2)$ in $\mathcal{D}$. The trouble with this is that in this case, $Hom(-,W)$ to a fixed vector space $W$ is contravariant in the first argument, as you explain above.

We need the **op** in order to have a covariant functor, in this case from $Vect^{op}_k \rightarrow Vect_k$.

Comment: So if I understood, the *op* is necessary because $f:V\rightarrow V'$ but $f^*$ needs its arrow to be "reversed" so it fits with what we want (respectively $F(f): F(V) \rightarrow F(V')$. Yes?

Comment: That's exactly right. Given $f: V\rightarrow V'$ in $\text{Vect}_k$, in order for $F(f)$=induced map on $Hom(-,W)$ to go from $F(V)= Hom(V,W)$ to  $F(V')=Hom(V',W)$, we need to reverse the arrows in our category. That is, we take $\mathcal{C} = \text{Vect}_k^{op}$.

Answer (score 1):

(Well, just to complement the answer above, maybe this can be of utility. I also always confuse this, so maybe writing down in detail it will make it clearer. )

Suppose $Hom(-,W)$ is a functor defined on $Vect_k \to Vect_k$.

Then it will take the objects of $Vect_k$, the vector space $V$, to objects of $Vect_k$ of the kind $Hom(V,W)$, that is, the vector space of linear maps $V \to W$.

And it will operate on morphisms too. The functor $Hom(-,W)$ will take $f:V \to V'$ and will give us

$$Hom(f,W): Hom(V,W) \to Hom(V',W)$$

by definition of functor  (that is, any functor has to respect $F(f): F(V) \to F(V')$).

But that is not right, because we want it operate as the composite-maker $f^*$:

$$f^*:\textbf{Hom}(V',W)\rightarrow \textbf{Hom}(V,W) $$
$$q \mapsto qf$$

for every morphism $q: V' \to W$ and map $ f: V \to V'$.

To fit this we instead take $Vect_k^{op}$ and work with contravariant functors. Then the functor $Hom(-,W)$ will take the morphism $f^{op}: V' \to V$ to the map:

$$Hom(f^{op},W): Hom(V',W) \to Hom(V,W).$$

And we are fine, because it will operate as $f^*$.

We could also define the covariant functor a $Hom(W,-)$ that operates as:

$$Hom(W,-): Vect_k \to Vect_k.$$

It will take, for every $q: W \to V$, a $f: V \to V'$ and will send to:

$$Hom(W,f): Hom(W, V) \to Hom(W, V')$$
$$q \mapsto fq.$$